# Check if tuple list is in increasing consecutive order in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

So I have a problem where I need to see if a list of positions which are in the form of (x,y) are in increasing consecutive order.

Just a for an example of whats meant to happen

```
[(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6)] it would return True, but
[(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7)] will return False
```

For example starting off like this.

```
is_in_order :: [Position] -> Bool
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what have you already tried? and what is with the list `[(1,2),(2,1)]`?

Comment: by the way haskell is usually using camelCase, therefore the naming `is_in_order` is usually `isInOrder`, I recommend using HLint to check for common stuff like that - it helped me improve my haskell skills a lot!

Comment: Thanks @epsilonhalbe I'll fix that to `isInOrder`. So I've just tried 
`isInOrder :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
 isInOrder [] = True
 isInOrder [x] = True
 isInOrder (x:y:xs) = x <= y && isInOrder (y:xs)`
And that just puts a list into order. I can't seem to get it to work with tuples and I need it in a case format

Comment: `unzip [(1,2), (1,3)] == ([1,1], [2,3])` might help.

Comment: Are you only checking the `y` values of these tuples? Or does the `x` play some role as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this seems to be an exercise example I will only provide some hints and not a full solution:

for just checking if all second tuples are consecutive a simple

```
checkConsecutive :: Num a => [a] -> Bool
checkConsecutive x = and $ zipWith (\x y -> y - x == 1) x (drop 1 x)
```

but I guess the case at hand should be more general - your `inOrder` function already provides a good base line

```
isConsecutive :: Num a => [a] -> Bool
isConsecutive [] = True
isConsecutive [x] = True
isConsecutive (x:y:xs) = consecutive x y && isConsecutive (y:xs)
  where consecutive :: (Num a, Num b) => (a,b) -> (a,b) -> Bool
        consecutive (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = ..
```

You write that you need `case` in order to do that, you can use a case expression in consecutive, but I don't think it would make the function clearer.

**Note:** you can simplify the function above to

```
isConsecutive (x:y:xs) = consecutive x y && isConsecutive (y:xs)
  where consecutive :: (Num a, Num b) => (a,b) -> (a,b) -> Bool
        consecutive (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = ..
isConsecutive _ = True
```

the `_` indicates a "catchall" pattern - i.e. it matches anything that is not matching the above patterns.

So the remaining task is to declare what it means for two tuples to be `consecutive`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement isInOrder this way:

```
isInOrder xs = all check $ zip xs $ tail xs where
    check ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) = x1<=x2 && y2-y1==1
```

You can modify check function the way you mean 'increasing consecutive order'